# Update field of object in array of array with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a mongo db with this model:

```
_id: ObjectId("5705005b240166e927f841cb")
chapters: {
    type: Array,
    default: [
        {
            "id":"capitulo_0",
            "active": true,
            "title": "CAPÍTULO 0 - INTRODUCCIÓN",
            "sections": [
                {
                    "title": "Institucional",
                    "type": "Video",
                    "id": "d74fb24654a2",
                    "url": "jPTG5P0528k",
                    "active": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"capitulo_1",
            "active": false,
            "title": "CAPÍTULO 1 - BIENVENIDA",
            "sections": [
                {
                    "title": "Introducción",
                    "type": "Video",
                    "url": "j2TG1P05k8k",
                    "id": "b2454d7f66de",
                    "active": false
                }
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

For the query i have the user_id and the id of the sections and **i need update the active field of the sections array**.

I'm doing this:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userId, 'chapters.sections':{$elemMatch: {id:sectionId}}}, {$set: {'sections.$.active': false}}).exec(function (err, doc) {console.log(doc)});
```

The active field not change.

How can I do it this query?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

I dont have your data so run this:

```
User.findOne({_id: userId, 'chapters.sections':{$elemMatch: {id:sectionId}}})
```

and see if you get response and record will be found, because your update looks fine.

**UPDATE:**

After seeing your data I think you are missing **chapters** in your query

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userId, 'chapters.sections':{$elemMatch: {id:sectionId}}}, {$set: {'chapters.sections.$.active': false}}).exec(function (err, doc) {console.log(doc)});
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi, i run this query and the response is the all objects into chapters array. I  only need the sections array match with the id.

Comment: Hi Tim, the response is long to post here, but is the same that the first post.

The array is longer (15 objects) but i only need to update the object of the array that matches with the sections.id

This query doesn't filter only the object with the sections.id, it retrives all the objects in the array.

Comment: With this query i have a mongo error 16837 with this message "cannot use the part (chapters of chapters.sections.0.active) to traverse the element"